# Select one row inside a group according to a criteria in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table as such (`tbl`):

```
+----+-----+------+-----+
| pk | grp | attr | val |
+----+-----+------+-----+
|  0 |   0 | ohif |   4 |
|  1 |   0 | foha |  56 |
|  2 |   0 | slns |   2 |
|  3 |   1 | faso |  11 |
|  4 |   1 | tepj |   4 |
|  5 |   2 | bnda |  12 |
|  6 |   2 | ojdf |   9 |
|  7 |   2 | anaw |   1 |
+----+-----+------+-----+
```

I would like to select one row from each group, in particular that with the maximum `val` for each group.

I can easily select `grp` and `val`:

```
SELECT grp, MAX(val)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY grp
```

Yielding this table (`tbl2`):

```
+-----+-----+
| grp | val |
+-----+-----+
|   0 |  56 |
|   1 |  11 |
|   2 |  12 |
+-----+-----+
```

However, I want this table:

```
+----+-----+------+-----+
| pk | grp | attr | val |
+----+-----+------+-----+
|  1 |   0 | foha |  56 |
|  3 |   1 | faso |  11 |
|  5 |   2 | bnda |  12 |
+----+-----+------+-----+
```

Since `(grp, val)` constitutes a key, I could left-join `tbl2` with `tbl` on same `grp` and `val`.

However, I was wondering if there was any other solution: in my real-world situation `tbl` is a pretty complex and heavy derived table, and I have the design constrain of not being able to use temp tables. Is there any way to order the rows inside each group according to `val` and to then take the first record for each group?

I'm on PostgreSQL 10, but a standard SQL solution would be the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postgres, the best approach is `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t.grp) t.*
FROM tbl
ORDER BY grp, val DESC;
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `(grp, val desc)`.

Comment: To integrate: PosgreSQL docs specifically mention _"SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. They [...] are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY [...]. Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first."_.  This makes your `DISTINCT ON` solution correct. It should be noted that the same guarantees on the ordering are not made for a `DISTINCT` clause!